# Jenkins Helm container and custom cacerts

Tags: java, ssl, jenkins, certificate, cacerts

Our company injects self-signed SSL certificates. Therefore, we need a custom cacerts file in Java applications to make connections out to the internet. Otherwise, we get certificate authority errors.

We are attempting to install Jenkins on our local Kubernetes cluster using the Jenkins Helm chart (https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/jenkinsci/jenkins), which comes with it's own Java VM. When Jenkins starts up, it is reaching out to the updats.jenkins.io, and failing with an error of:

```
Unable to retrieve JSON from https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json?version=2.387.1:
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I'm guessing that replacing the cacerts file in the included Java VM will fix the problem, but I'm not sure how to do it. How do you modify files on Docker image that are referenced by a Helm chart?

Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom values yaml file, and provide the details that are different from values.yaml, use the custom  values yaml when applying your helm chart

```
 javaOpts: >
    -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/var/jenkins_keystore/keystore.jks
    -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
    -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification=true 
    -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldapURLParsing="legacy"
```

Comment: Your example is for the keystore, not the cacerts file -- isn't that different?

Also, how do I get the new file inside the jenkins container?